# fs-uae: how to load qemu plugin on Linux?

Tags: emulators

I have fs-uae on Slackware,compiled by [slackbuilds](http://slackbuilds.org/).
I have compiled also qemu-plugin for ppc board emulation
But when I run it, it doesn't load the plugin nor search for it.
I have these shared libraries:

```
$HOME/Documents/FS-UAE/Plugins/qemu-uae/3.6.0qemu2.2.0/qemu-uae.so
```

and

```
/usr/lib/fs-uae/plugins/qemu-uae/3.6.0qemu2.2.0/qemu-uae.so
/usr/lib64/fs-uae/plugins/qemu-uae/3.6.0qemu2.2.0/qemu-uae.so
```

My fs-uae version is 2.4.3 and qemu plugin is 11 revision git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found [here](http://fs-uae.net/plugins/comment-page-1) : the stable 2.4 doesn't support ppc plugins,upgraded to latest devel will work.